# passing ksh array variable to oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, ksh

we are having a issue where we need to pass the text file value as a array variable from KSH script to oracle procedure.

is it possible to pass ksh array variable to oracle proc(parameter as array)

Thanks in advance.

## let me give some more details.

I have shall script with a array variable holding few value, i would like to pass the array variable to oracle proc as array.

but whenever i execute my shall script it takes only first value and "Zara" gets inserted into sp_table.

is there any way i can pass unix array variable as array itself.  ( i was expecting output as all the NAMES in table sp_table)

```
Test.sh
 =========
#!/bin/sh
lookup=$1

NAME[0]="Zara"
NAME[1]="Qadir"
NAME[2]="Mahnaz"
NAME[3]="Ayan"
NAME[4]="Daisy"

sqlplus -S ddsdbo/Higlmk67ctX123@TPBQ.WORLD << EOF
DECLARE
L_SUPPLY_NAME_ARR DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2A;
BEGIN
sp_t('$NAME');
END;
/
EOF
```

## sp_t (PROCEDURE)

```
create or replace PROCEDURE sp_t (L_SUPPLY_NAME_ARR DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2A  ) as
   begin 
   FOR  i IN 1 .. L_SUPPLY_NAME_ARR.COUNT
       LOOP
         insert into sp_table values (L_SUPPLY_NAME_ARR(i));
       END LOOP;
       commit;
end;
```

Comment: I know it's been a while...but actually you are only passing along the index 0 of the array. To send the whole array you should use ${NAME[@]} instead.